# Include a custom module on Spree and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to add my module to my `class_eval` on Spree.

This is located on: `lib/spree/core/app/models/spree/payment/processing.rb`

Tried with the following:

```
module Spree
   Payment.class_eval do
     require GatewayError

   end
end
```

I am trying to include the following located on: `lib/spree/error_override.rb`

```
module Spree
  module GatewayError


  end
end
```

The error I'm getting when I try to load the server is:

```
`block in <module:Spree>': uninitialized constant Spree::GatewayError (NameError)
```

Its my first time trying to include my own module to a class, would be awesome if someone can point me in the right direction.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you restarted your server? Also if you fire up a rails console what is the result of `> Spree::GatewayError`?

Comment: My server and console are not started, and I get same error when I try to start either one `lib/spree/core/app/models/spree/payment/processing.rb:3:in `block in <module:Spree>': uninitialized constant Spree::GatewayError (NameError)`

Comment: Just commet out the line with require and try running the console. Can it fing the module in the console?

Comment: good thinking! I get `NameError: uninitialized constant Spree::GatewayError` I guess its not finding it, do I need to require/include it in config/applcation.rb ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to manually require the file during initialization process.

**config/initializers/require.rb:**

```
# put here all files that you want to require manually
require "#{Rails.root}/lib/spree/error_override.rb"
```

And that's it - your module is now ready to use ;)

Comment: that didn't work for me, I tried a few other variations as well, but they didn't work either, not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: made a few changes to answer, thank you for your help!